# 3D Trigonometry subtended at an angle of 45 degrees

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to understand this for so long but I can't seem to understand how to draw this as a diagram. Sorry the image is a bit blurry

[image: 3D Trigonometry Question]

**Here is the question typed out:**
An observer's eye is 2m above the ground. A vertical pole fixed in the ground subtends an angle of 45 degrees at the observer's eye. The angle of depression of the base of the flagpole from the eye is 15 degrees. Show that the height of the flagpole is $2[1+\tan(30°)\tan(75°)]$ metres.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

As you can see, In the image P is the observer, AB is the pole, given PL = height of observer = 2 m; to find AB, we are finding AQ and QB using trigonometric properties. We know QB =PL = 2m. Thus, we find PQ using tan property in triangle PQB then use this PQ to find AQ in triangle PAQ, then AB =AQ+QB.